# Measuring oscillation erratically or wave peridods

Tags: kurtosis, differences

I am trying to use a statistic that shows how erratic one of my parameters is acting. We can see this graphically:

[image: Normal]

[image: Erratic]

Originally I attempted to find the sum of the absolute difference between each point so:

R:    `df[, sum(abs(diff(param))), file]`

However this didn't really stand out how I imagined. I guess this makes sense as if one series goes up 1, down 1, up 1 etc that will give the same result as up 1, up 1, ... , up 1, down 1, down 1, ... etc

The idea I have to solve this is to ignore how much movement there is but for every movement in the same direction, increase the value as a sequence and then sum all the sequences.

So for the first case we would simply get the sum of 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 (probably not that flat but hopefully you get the point). And the second one would be more like the sum of of 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

I'm wondering if there is a method I am unaware of that does this job better, as this crude way will ignore how much the parameter has moved.

I have also tried `df[, sum(diff(param)^2), file]`

I would guess something like the skewness or actually the kurtosis could work,  but when looking at the kurtosis I get values of `3.060` and `3.057` which seem very similar.

Physicists/Engineers must have a way of doing this?

Comment: sorry, the middle is the focus. The behavior at the start and end are normal. Fast Fourier transformations may be useful but its been a decade since I did Fourier series at uni!

Comment: the top graph is whats expected, the bottom is what im trying to highlight, statistically

Comment: why don't you calculate the coefficient of variation on the relevant portion of your data? it's similar to signal/noise ratio

Comment: was thinking I could smooth the data then find the sum of squared differences or I could only sum differences greater than a certain threshold that accounts for noise.

Comment: The top graph is expected behavior. So what im calling noise are the step changes in the middle of that graph that are within expected variability. The second graph we see much larger step changes that are not expected. I say the middle of the graph as the start and end shows the machine starting up/shutting down.

Comment: your terminology is unusual, so maybe you could draw arrows and highlights on your plots. that would help people understand your objective

Comment: I simply want a stat that shows the difference in behavior between the two graphs such that I can look at thousands of these and determine how many have the 'unusual' behavior.